# How do I handle errors when deploying aws ecs via the Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ecs

When deploying aws ecs through the Jenkins pipeline
Why does an error occur when the result is not set in the environment variable when registering a work definition?

[jenkins error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSO5N.png)

[jenkinsfile code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S88Wh.png)

```
stage('Aws ECS Deploy') {
            environment {
                TASK_ECS = sh '$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://api-server/definition.json | jq --raw-output .taskDefinition.revision)'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'aws ecs update-service --cluster default --service api --task-definition api-server:$TASK_ECS'
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the agent where the pipeline job is running has these commands (aws ecs register-task-definition) available.